# is "%LIKE%" faster than executing multiple queries?

Tags: database-design

for example, each user on my site has 2 phone numbers (i.e. let say 1234 and 6789) .

but about performance , which is faster:

to save the numbers in one column(separated by comma,like `[1234,6789]` ), and thus, searching the columns with :

```
select  userID from table where number LIKE %1234%
```

or saving values into 2 columns

```
select  userID from table where number1=1234 or number2=1234
```

which will be faster? lets say i have thousands or millions of rows.

Answer (score 3):

This is bad - it is a table scan

```
LIKE %1234
```

But thousands of rows is not much

Best would be to have second table with phone

```
phone:  
userID PK FK to user   
number PK



select * 
from user 
join phone 
       on phone.userID = user.userid 
      and phone.numer = '1234'
```

if you don't want to fix the data design then two column with = will be faster

Answer (score 0):

I think you've confused some syntax.

Best way to do this is

```
SELECT My_Fields[,,,,] FROM My_Table WHERE number LIKE '123%' OR number LIKE '456%';
```

This will work for `VARCHAR`s, but not for `INTEGER`s. But, `'%LIKE%'` doesn't exist, unless you're trying to pick out the string `'LIKE'` from a longer string.

A search for the string - LIKE %123% makes no sense - it has to be between two single quotes - i.e. like LIKE '%123%';

If the string you're searching for is "embedded" in the phone number string - i.e. it's  `VARCHAR(25)` - or similar - and you're searching for `123` in `'01-24-123...'`, then your search string is [non-sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) which can lead to significant performance hits.

To search within the string, use LIKE '%123%' - but, as I've said, it will not use indexes - check out the URL I've referenced for sargable.

All of this should be carefully analysed before system launch - unless you have only a couple of thousand records.

I was in College and the Library had introduced a new cataloguing system  -  you could be there **minutes** before a search came up for this very reason, - I told the librarian that this was a basic mistake and that the people who designed the system should be shot - she replied, "No, that would be too good for them!" :-)

Comment: I think you confuse the question

Comment: Show me where I am confused? My remarks about being sargable seem to be what you're driving at. I don't see how a second table is relevant though - that the query is sargable or not is a completely separate matter from different tables.

Comment: Well for one that query does not even return the proper results

Comment: You're being disingenuous - I made it clear (from the URL I referenced) that there is a huge difference between searching for '123%' and '%123%' - the first is sargable, the second is not. I've made that more explicit in an edit to my post - but I fail to see how all of this is relevant to your post. Your post about searching for "= '1234' is a complete red herring, doesn't answer the question and is misleading. Searching for an exact match on '1234' is meaningless, unless the string **is** "1234". If it begins with 1234, then it's '1234%', but the OP seems to want to search more generally.

Comment: U can read the question how you chose. I read select  userID from table where number1=1234 or number2=1234

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you are somewhat correct. However, I've rarely seen phone numbers that can be readily broken into two `INTEGER` parts. For example, where I'm from, the area code is 01 - not a valid integer. I'm going to wait until the OP can clarify. I **still** say that the string "LIKE %1234%" is meaningless - it needs to be quoted - "LIKE '%1234%'" or similar - note separate single and double quote at end of search string.